# Facing An Issue while bower update Symfony2

Tags: symfony-2.8

Hi I have cloned a symfony2.8 project from bitbucket on my local system.when I tried to run project on my local system after cloned it, It is showing blank page So i want to update the dependencies and want to add vendor using bower to my project so that it will work.I am using following command :

var/www/html/myproject/bower update

But it display me following error :

```
bower jquery-visible#~1.1.0 ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote -
-tags --heads https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible.git", exit 
code of #128 fatal: unable to access 
'https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible.git/': Failed to connect to 
github.com port 443: No route to host

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/customd/jquery-
visible.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: No route to 
host
```

I have tried a lot to identified but could not get any solution. I am using ubuntu 14.04 and symfony2.8

Please help,what could be the issue.

Thanks advance

Comment: where you got bower, i think composer is fine for symfony(php)

Comment: I am using bower as well, with composer

Comment: I have resolve the issue now..thanks